# How get mobaxterm work with kubectl?

Tags: kubernetes, mobaxterm

**mobaxterm is not able to read kube config setting when using with kubectl.**

I am using MobaXterm_21.2 installed version.
When i run - kubectl version, its woking as expected

```
 kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"14", GitVersion:"v1.14.3", GitCommit:"5e53fd6bc17c0dec8434817e69b04a25d8ae0ff0", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-06-06T01:44:30Z", G
oVersion:"go1.12.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"windows/amd64"}
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp [::1]:8080: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

But it is not able to reade the .kube/config file or able to pickup the config file given through ENV variable KUBECONFIG or --kubeconfig. See bellow response

```
  export KUBECONFIG=/drives/path/to/config/file.config
                                                                                                                                                                                        ✔

  kubectl config view
apiVersion: v1
clusters: []
contexts: []
current-context: ""
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users: []
```

And neither is below working -

```
 kubectl config --kubeconfig=/drives/path/to/config/file.config  view
apiVersion: v1
clusters: []
contexts: []
current-context: ""
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users: []
```

**This is a kind of blocking issues for me. Can anyone guide me on how to make kubectl work in mobaxterm. Any help will be highly appreciated.**